# Como manipular o background-Image com javascript ? tenho 3 imagens que deve ser alterada no body conforme o periodo do dia, alguem sabe como resolver?

Tags: javascript, html, css

já tentei com este e outras combinações dentro de estruturas de decisão porem não funcionou

document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundImage = "img/manha.jpg"
document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundImage = "img/tarde.jpg"
document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundImage = "img/noite.jpg"

Comment: Experimente com document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('img/manha.jpg')";

Answer (score -1):

Use `url('URL ou endereço relativo')`:

Exemplo:

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('img/manha.jpg')";
```

Existem mais [exemplos](https://www.bing.com/search?q=HTML%20javascript%20set%20body%20background%20image).